# RegExp replace do not replaces with pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, pattern-matching, regexp-replace

I want to replace #### by ##-## (# := any digit symbol).

```
if (/^([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$/.test(str)) {       
    str = str.replace("/^([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$/", "$1-$2");
    console.log(str);
}
```

In console I get #### (not ##-##).
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a regex to the replace function not a string - in your case you are trying to replace the string literal `/^([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$/`

```
str = str.replace(/^([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$/, "$1-$2");
```

```js
var str = '4455';
snippet.log('before: ' + str);
str = str.replace(/^([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$/, "$1-$2");
snippet.log('after: ' + str);
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```